# What is routePath */*/* mean?

Tags: magento2

So I found the code in the module-swatches there is class Called `RenderLayered`. here is the snipped code :

**`/vendor/magento/magento-swatches/Block/LayeredNavigation/RenderLayered.php`**

```
public function buildUrl($attributeCode, $optionId)
{
    $query = [$attributeCode => $optionId];
    return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $query]);
}
```

What is the routepath Params mean here `*/*/*` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any Magento route (M1 or M2), an asterisk `*` means 'use the current value'.

Three of them `*/*/*` means getUrl for exactly the same request as you're currently on: The same route (part 1), controller path (part 2), and action (part 3).

In this case, your example block is a renderer for layered navigation, so that means it will output the current URL (with the exception of the extra `$query` parameters), regardless of what page you're actually on: It could be a category page, or search results, or a custom landing page that uses layered navigation--the same exact block with the same `getUrl()` call will work for all of them.

You will often see this pattern in admin form actions and redirects, typically leaving the first two parts `*` and specifying the third, like: `*/*/save` (meaning go to 'save' action on the current route and controller path).

Comment: do you know how to get the Route Path ?

Comment: I need to change the value so I can give an additional prefix to the url.

Comment: @GujaratSantana You're going to need to give more information and context. I suggest opening a new question and explaining *exactly* what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: How do we point a current product page, as product page has SEO friendly URLs are enabled and it looks something like foo.com/fancy-product

Comment: @Adnan: For a product, you generally load the product model (as say `$product`), then call `$product->getProductUrl()` for its SEO URL.